# Get height/width of image in Javascript (ideally without loading the image at all)

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this has already been answered, but I can't find it if so.

I want to find the height and width of an image file in Javascript. I don't actually need to show the image in the page, just the height and width.

At the moment I've got the following code, but it's returning height and width 0 (in Mozilla 5).

```
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "./filename.jpg";
  var imgHeight = img.height;
  var imgWidth = img.width;
  alert("image height = "  + imgHeight + ", image width = " + imgWidth);
```

The file definitely exists, it's in the same directory as the HTML, and it doesn't have height and width 0 :)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the image is not loaded, it won't have its' height and width set. You have to wait until the image is fully loaded, then inspect its' size. Maybe something along these lines:

```
function getWidthAndHeight() {
    alert("'" + this.name + "' is " + this.width + " by " + this.height + " pixels in size.");
    return true;
}
function loadFailure() {
    alert("'" + this.name + "' failed to load.");
    return true;
}
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.name = "image.jpg";
myImage.onload = getWidthAndHeight;
myImage.onerror = loadFailure;
myImage.src = "image.jpg";
```

Answer (score 11):

The following code will get you the width/height without waiting for the image to load completely, making it significantly faster than the other solutions here.

For testing change `abc123` in image source to any random string to prevent caching.

There is a [JSFiddle  Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ct1wtktm/) as well.

```
<div id="info"></div>
<img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Island_Archway,_Great_Ocean_Rd,_Victoria,_Australia_-_Nov_08.jpg?abc123">

<script>
getImageSize($('#image'), function(width, height) {
    $('#info').text(width + ',' + height);
});

function getImageSize(img, callback) {
    var $img = $(img);

    var wait = setInterval(function() {
        var w = $img[0].naturalWidth,
            h = $img[0].naturalHeight;
        if (w && h) {
            clearInterval(wait);
            callback.apply(this, [w, h]);
        }
    }, 30);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Is it documented in a spec anywhere that the browser will set naturalWidth and naturalHeight as soon as possible, or is this just a side effect of certain implementations? Do you have any references for this approach?

Comment: I am also interested to know that, if the author is still available.

Answer (score 5):

The height and width properties of an image element (like the offsetHeight and offsetWidth properties of any element),
return 0 instead of the actual values until it has been added to some document (and if its style.display attribute is not set to "none").
A common way to work around this is displaying the image outside the visible area of your page; your users will not see it, and its height and width properties will return the actual values instead of 0.
Then you should remove the image from the document.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "./filename.jpg";
img.style.position = "absolute";
img.style.left = -9999;             // Image width must not exceed 9999 pixels
img.style.visibility = "hidden";    // Maybe you can remove this
document.body.appendChild(img);
var imgHeight = img.height;
var imgWidth = img.width;
alert("image height = "  + imgHeight + ", image width = " + imgWidth); 
document.body.removeChild(img);     // Removes the image from the DOM (This does not destroy the image element)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution get the image width/height **without loading the image at all**.

The trick here, is only load the first 1k of the image, where the metadata is placed, and then parse this info.
This code only works for .jpg images.
Need some adaptation for work with another formats.

```js
function jpg1k(url) {

  // indexOf for multi-pattern
  function indexOfMulti(arr, pattern) {
    var found,
        _index = arr.indexOf(pattern[0]);

    while (_index > -1) {
      found = true;

      var _idx = _index;
      for (var patt of pattern) {
        if (arr.indexOf(patt, _idx) !== _idx) {
          found = false;
          break;
        }

        _idx++;
      }

      if (found) {
        return _index;
      }

      _index = arr.indexOf(pattern[0], _index + 1);
    }

    return -1;
  }
  

  const SOF_B = [ 0xFF, 0xC0 ], // Start Of Frame (Baseline),
        SOF_P = [ 0xFF, 0xC2 ]; // Start Of Frame (Progressive)

  
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState != 4) {
        return;
      }

      const JPG = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);

      const IDX_SOF_B = indexOfMulti(JPG, SOF_B);
      if (IDX_SOF_B > -1) {
        var h = JPG.slice(IDX_SOF_B + 5, IDX_SOF_B + 7),
            w = JPG.slice(IDX_SOF_B + 7, IDX_SOF_B + 9);

        h = parseInt(h[0].toString(2) + h[1].toString(2).padStart(8, '0'), 2);
        w = parseInt(w[0].toString(2) + w[1].toString(2).padStart(8, '0'), 2);
        return res({ w: w, h: h });
      }

      const IDX_SOF_P = indexOfMulti(JPG, SOF_P);
      if (IDX_SOF_P > -1) {
        var h = JPG.slice(IDX_SOF_P + 5, IDX_SOF_P + 7),
            w = JPG.slice(IDX_SOF_P + 7, IDX_SOF_P + 9);

        h = parseInt(h[0].toString(2) + h[1].toString(2).padStart(8, '0'), 2);
        w = parseInt(w[0].toString(2) + w[1].toString(2).padStart(8, '0'), 2);
        return res({ w: w, h: h });
      }

      return rej({ w: -1, h: -1 });
    };

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-1024');
    xhr.send(null);
  });
  
}

jpg1k('path_to_your_image.jpg')
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: but this loads the image... once you have the readyState == 4, then you already received reply so you have all data (not only 1st KB)

Comment: sorry... missed the 1024byte header

Answer (score 0):

If you check this link here is a method to get all the image dimensions in a directory with PHP which checks it without having to load it to the page. This might help you. You can pass it to your js with a

```
var dimensions = <?php echo json_encode($imageDimensions)?>
```

[PHP Get dimensions of images in dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809985/php-get-dimensions-of-images-in-dir)

I think this is a better approach if you really don't want to load the images